# Finite dimensional algebras with finite global dimension.

Tags: ring-theory, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra, global-dimension

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, $k$ is a field, with a finite global dimension. I wonder if that implies $A$ is tame or finite type? or more generally is there a relation between these two notions?

Comment: A path algebra is hereditary and it can be of wild representation type: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5895/what-are-tame-and-wild-hereditary-algebras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really expanding on egreg's comment: there are wild algebras of any finite global dimension.  Indeed, if you take $A$ to be a wild hereditary algebra (these exist: take the path algebra of any connected non-Dynkin or non-extended-Dynkin quiver), and $B$ to be any algebra of global dimension $n$, then the algebra $A\times B$ is wild of global dimension $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, does $n$ have to be positive, or this works for zero also?

Comment: It has to be positive.  A finite-dimensional algebra of global dimension zero is semisimple, and thus of finite representation type.

Comment: And how about the converse? Do tame algebras have finite global dimension?

Comment: Even representation-finite algebras can be of infinite global dimension.  An example would be $k[x]/(x^n)$ for any $n\geq 2$.